# acumos model image build error in dockerize

Tags: acumos

I ran into a mistake when I was onboarding create image and didn't know how to fix it. What should I do?

The same operation is working on my home workstation but not working in office workstation, is the proxy's problem?

follow the log:

```
2018.12.11.15.05.52  DEBUG  Step 8/16 : RUN echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" | tee /etc/resolv.conf > /dev/null
2018.12.11.15.05.52  DEBUG  
2018.12.11.15.05.52  DEBUG   ---> Using cache
2018.12.11.15.05.52  DEBUG   ---> 44aa4855b1cb
2018.12.11.15.05.52  DEBUG  Step 9/16 : RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get -y install libgtk2.0-dev
2018.12.11.15.05.52  DEBUG  
2018.12.11.15.05.52  DEBUG   ---> Running in 36a688ff26f2
2018.12.11.15.08.08  DEBUG  Err deb.debian.org jessie InRelease
Err deb.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease
Err security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease
2018.12.11.15.08.08  DEBUG  Err deb.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 10.1.0.6:3128:
2018.12.11.15.08.08  DEBUG  Err security.debian.org jessie/updates Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 10.1.0.6:3128:
2018.12.11.15.08.08  DEBUG  Err deb.debian.org jessie-updates Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to 10.1.0.6:3128:    
2018.12.11.15.08.12  DEBUG  Reading package lists...
2018.12.11.15.08.16  DEBUG  
2018.12.11.15.08.20  DEBUG  [91mW: Failed to fetch deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 10.1.0.6:3128:
W: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 10.1.0.6:3128:
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to 10.1.0.6:3128:
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
[0m
2018.12.11.15.08.24  DEBUG  Reading package lists...
2018.12.11.15.08.27  DEBUG  
2018.12.11.15.08.31  DEBUG  Building dependency tree...
2018.12.11.15.08.31  DEBUG  
Reading state information...
2018.12.11.15.08.31  DEBUG  
2018.12.11.15.08.31  DEBUG  [91mE: Unable to locate package libgtk2.0-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libgtk2.0-dev'
[0m
2018.12.11.15.08.32  DEBUG Notifycom.github.dockerjava.api.exception.DockerClientException: Could not build image: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get -y install libgtk2.0-dev' returned a non-zero code: 100
2018.12.11.15.08.32  DEBUG  Send Notification to DB Ended
2018.12.11.15.08.32  DEBUG  Onboarding Failed, Reverting failed solutions and artifacts.
```

Comment: Are you using the All-In-One (AIO) installation?  Is your environment simple Docker or are you using Kubernetes? What language are you using - Python, R, Java? The dockerize step relies on a local proxy server, something like Squid3. I will have to check in that installation what proxy is established.

Comment: yes ,i used All-in-one installation.the environment  is docker. I userd python language.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. The log excerpt above starts at step 8 of 16. Can you post the entire log starting at step 1? Would you also please search the configuration files for the string "10.1.0.6:3128" and report where that occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this delayed comment, hope it will help new comers.

I have faced this issue twice,

- The first time it was due to a disck space issue, once I cleaned my repos by removing old useless big files it was ok
- The second time I resolved it by "sudo apt-get update"